# Can I put a T-mobile sim card into the SIM800L Module?

Tags: gsm

I am trying to connect my SIM800L module to my arduino, but am confused what kinds of sim cards work. My phone currently is an IPhone XS, and I would like to take my tmobile sim card from there and put it into the module. I talked to a tmobile rep and they said my card could handle 2G devices. Would this work? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try it first, then post a question if you have problems .... what does your question have to do with `gps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work but you'd be better off getting a 2G dedicated card.  Hologram.io has a developer card that is $5 and free 1MB / month or something.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, the cost looks great too. thanks!